# Where does the saying get a rope originate?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Is it truly a racial comment to lynching or is it a reference to wild west judgement with no jury?

Comment: Wasn't the "wild west judgement with no jury" a lynching??

Answer (score -1):

The question is being posed because someone used the term “get a rope” referencing the Picante Salsa advertisement from the 90’s and someone turned it into a “racial” statement and said it was about racial lynchings. I have never heard this used specific to racially motivated lynchings - definitely used in old west judgements past with no jury present which were not racial necessarily but could be.